# Using an unsigned int as binary to implement a set in c++

Tags: c++, integer, unsigned

I have an assignment that requires me to implement a set using an unsigned integer.

Normally, I would use the in-built c++ set to store numbers from 1-9.

The task is to create an alternate data structure that holds which numbers are in your set via an unsigned integer.

For example, if I had a number '1', '3', and '4' in my set, it would look like:

000001101

This can be done by toggling each bit from a 0 to 1 when a new item is inserted.

But when I initially create my 'unsigned int' via the constructor:

```
class unsignedIntSet {

private:

  unsigned int valuesInSet;
  int noOfElements;

public:

  unsignedIntSet() : noOfElements(0), valuesInSet(000000000){

    cout<<"the values in the set are: "<<valuesInSet;
  }

...

};
```

It prints: "the values in the set are: 0256"

How would I be able to treat the member variable 'valuesInSet' as the literal value I give it, 000000000, rather than have it, for some reason, be converted.

Comment: Post code that compiles, runs, and shows the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you get an output of `0256` this way. The output I get is `0`. Also note that `000000000` is an octal literal (but the result is `0` either way). What you're looking for is `0b00000000` - here you can toggle each bit and get the correct number. For instance `0b00001010` is `10`.

Probably the easiest way to print its binary representation is to do it with a bitset. Include `<bitset>` and do this:

```
std::cout << "the values in the set are: "
    << std::bitset<sizeof(unsigned int) * CHAR_BIT>(valuesInSet);
```

I got the suspicion that using `bitset` would make the assignment pointless though (as that's kind of what you're supposed to implement), so instead you could also try

```
for (int i = sizeof(unsigned int)* CHAR_BIT -1; i >= 0; i--) {
    std::cout << bool(valuesInSet & (1 << i));
}
```